# How do I go about making individual parts of a material more shiny without making the whole material as a whole more shiney?

Tags: materials, node-editor

So I am practicing with materials and I was curious if there is a way to make it so that these individual colored specs are more metallic and/or shiny without making the material as a whole more shiny?

Down below is a screenshot of what the material looks like and the node set up. And here is a link to the **[blend file](https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fo/pz9oqq7nd6epo4vrh75jt/h?dl=0&rlkey=zm3ijhmbvh17wxrdve3wah4e4)**.[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simple - connect the *ColorRamp* you're using as your mix factor to the *Metallic* and the inverse to the *Roughness* (for reference, for Metallic - white=metal and black=non-metal and for roughness White=rough and Black=Shiny, shades of grey are partly shiny/rough depending on the darkness). I clamped them a bit further first with another *ColorRamp* to get rid of the gradients in the falloff around the edges. Don't forget to turn off your *Clearcoat* (this was causing the whole thing to appear shiny regardless of anything else):

[image]

Alternatively, if you want to keep the *Clearcoat* over the "gems", you can connect that up as well using the same map you use for the *Metallic* input:

[image: Clear2]